# Opposite of array_tree in purrr package?

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I was wondering if there is a function that is the opposite of the `array_tree` function from the purrr package.

Specifically I would like a function (lets call it `list_untree` -better suggestions welcome) that will do the following. If `a` is a multidimensional array and `m` is some vector specifying the margins for `array_tree`.

```
l <- array_tree(a, margin=m)
a <- list_untree(l, margin=m)
```

How can I write something like this efficiently if it does not already exist.

**For More Motivation:**
I am particularly interested in doing computations on `l` using the map function and then plugging the result into the `list_untree` function.

Comment: Somehow I feel this would be doable with `apply`? Please share a small example and what the expected result would be.